# Why do I keep getting NaN as my output?

Tags: java

I have created a loan payment calculator. Whenever I type in any input the output shows up as NaN. Any ideas to what I could change. The first section of code is the main method. The second is another class.

MAIN METHOD

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the amount borrowed: ");
        double amountBorrowed = kbd.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
        int intRate = kbd.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the minimum length of loan: ");
        int minLength = kbd.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the maximum length of loan: ");
        int loanLength = kbd.nextInt();
        while (loanLength < minLength) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input: Input must be greater than minimum length of loan");
            System.out.println("Enter the maximum length of loan: ");
            loanLength = kbd.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = minLength; i <= loanLength; i++) {
            double payment = LoanCalc.monthlyPayment(amountBorrowed,loanLength, intRate);
            System.out.println(payment);
        }

    }

}
```

CLASS

```
public class LoanCalc {
    public static double monthlyPayment(double amountBorrowed, int loanLength, int intRate) {

        double interestRate;
        double monthlyPayment;

        interestRate = intRate / 100 / 12;

        monthlyPayment = (interestRate * amountBorrowed) / (1- Math.pow((1 + interestRate) , - loanLength * 12 ));

        return monthlyPayment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, without a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and sample input/output, it's tough to say for sure, but I'm guessing you've got rounding problems in this line: `interestRate = intRate / 100 / 12;` All those variable are integers, so you always get integer division...

Comment: @HenryKeiter:  The code above *isn't* an SSCCE?  It's actually quite perfect to figure out what's going on (and it works, albeit trivially, for all inputs anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first hunch would be NaN is being introduced in [Math.pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)) as has a *huge list* of conditions that will make it return NaN - see what the *actual* input values are.

And, now *about* the actual values - the `interestRate` will be wrong (and likely 0) because *integer division* is being done. Try:

```
 interestRate = (double)intRate / 100 / 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing by zero when you work out `monthlyPayment`.

Because you do an integer division when you calculate `interestRate`, you finish up with zero.  So on the next line, you're actually doing `Math.pow(1, -loanLength * 12)` which will always give you 1.  You're subtracting the result from 1 and dividing by it.  Hence division by zero.

You need that `intRate` parameter to be a `double`, not an `int`, so that you don't get integer division when you calculate `interestRate`.

You COULD do this with a cast (as per the other two answers that are currently here), but I think you'd be better off having it as a `double` from the beginning - when you first declare `intRate` in `main`, when you fetch it from the scanner, and also when you pass it to `monthlyPayment`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `interestRate = intRate / 100 / 12` is performing **integer division**.  None of those dividends/divisors are converted to a decimal value, so you get 0.

That makes this expression interesting:

```
 Math.pow((1 + interestRate) , - loanLength * 12 )
```

The result of that is 1 (since 1 to any power is always 1).  You subtract 1 from that to get 0.

Now, [something interesting happens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) when you divide by zero in an IEEE 754 floating point value - you get `NaN`.

> The result of a floating-point division is determined by the rules of
>   IEEE 754 arithmetic:
>
> - If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - If the result is not NaN, the sign of the result is positive if both
>     operands have the same sign, and negative if the operands have
>     different signs.
> - Division of an infinity by an infinity results in NaN.
> - Division of an infinity by a finite value results in a signed
>     infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.
> - Division of a finite value by an infinity results in a signed zero.
>     The sign is determined by the rule stated above.
> - **Division of a zero by a zero results in NaN;** division of zero by any
>     other finite value results in a signed zero. The sign is determined by
>     the rule stated above.

What you should be doing is casting `intRate` to a `double` instead.

```
interestRate = (double)intRate / 100 / 12;
```